# SQL-query returns a value instead of comparing against it

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this query:

```
SELECT  web.KONTO, LAGKART.VARENUMMER, LAGKART.GRUPPE, LAGPRIS.PRIS, LAGKART.VARENAVN1, LAGPRIS.LXBENUMMER, LAGPRIS.ENHED
FROM    LAGKART
INNER JOIN
        LAGPRIS
ON      LAGKART.VARENUMMER = LAGPRIS.VARENUMMER
INNER JOIN
        DEBWEBVARER web
ON      web.VARENUMMER = LAGPRIS.VARENUMMER
WHERE   LAGPRIS.ENHED = web.ENHED
        AND web.KONTO = '  00000001'
ORDER BY
        LAGKART.VARENAVN1 ASC
```

And it yields:

```
  KONTO   |VARENUMMER|GRUPPE|PRIS          |VARENAVN1|LXBENUMMER|ENHED

  00000001|003       |1     |0.000000000000|765402   |stk

  00000001|003       |1     |0.000000000000|4418625  |kg
```

The problem is:

In table DEBWEBVARER there are 0 rows containing KONTO = '  00000001'

Anyone able to figure out why it specifies KONTO as '  00000001' instead of comparing?

Comment: If you need clarification, please ask for it, and I will reply swiftly

Comment: are you filtering on  '  00000001' or = '00000001' ??

Comment: the filter is: 

WHERE web.KONTO = '  00000001' (I've not put in spaces here, but another character (0160) so it displays caorrectly to you.

Comment: could you clarify what you mean by "why it specifies KONTO as ' 00000001' instead of comparing" ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In table `DEBWEBVARER` there are `0` rows containing `KONTO = ' 00000001'`

There is at least one row containing `KONTO = '  00000001'` (with `2` leading spaces), which is returned by your query.

If you issue this query:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    DEBWEBVARER web
WHERE   web.KONTO = '  00000001'
```

, you can see what does this row (or rows) look like.

Could you also please issue the following query:

```
SELECT  TOP 1
        CAST(KONTO AS BINARY),
        CAST('  00000001' AS BINARY),
FROM    DEBWEBVARER web
WHERE   web.KONTO = '  00000001'
```

again, copying and pasting your filter into both `WHERE` and `SELECT` clauses?

Comment: No, the table DEBWEBVARER only contains rows where KONTO = '  12345678'

Comment: @jAST: issue the query, copying and pasting your filter from the original query

Comment: For some reason that returns all the rows. But the problem is, no rows have a KONTO, where the field equals = ' |00000001'

Comment: You have a vertical pipe | character in there.  Just try running the query.

Comment: @jAST if the only value in the DEBWEBVARER.KONTO is '  12345678' there is no way it would display records web.KONTO = '  00000001' unless you use alias web for another table or something like this

Answer (score 1):

What field type is KONTO, sounds like customer.  If this is an int then both values are 1 and thus the same.

Also, is that whitespace in KONTO = ' 00000001' meant to be there or is that simply from editing text for answer?

You may wish to explicitly set comparison to type varchar and then compare (using sql convert or cast operators on both KONTO and the string you wish to match).

Comment: KONTO is varchar(10). Yes, the whitespace is meant to be there. It's an old NAVISION-db converted to a MS SQL Server, so it's all messed up I'm afraid :)

The format for an account (KONTO) is: "  ########"

Answer (score 1):

Issue solved:

The DB-admin has setup some wierd filtering on the DB. I have no idea what he is doing, but apparently when I select everything it only return 253 rows, when there are infact 33000 rows in the table.

So the rows with KONTO = '  00000001' are infact there, but didn't show up when I selected "Show all table data".

Thank you for your answers, and sorry to have wasted your time in this case :)